# Couchbase composite keys search

Tags: nosql, couchbase, couchbase-view

I have the following array:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "xp is 20" [1]=> string(19) "level between 9, 50" [2]=> string(20) "cars between 100,200" }
```

First is **field** than is **operator** and after is the **value** searched for.
My view is as follows:

```
function (doc) { emit([doc.data.xp, doc.data.level, doc.data.cars]) }
```

Basically I want to search for key xp equal to 20 AND level between 9 AND 50 AND cars BETWEEN 100 AND 200.

Can I do that in Couchbase and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that, at least now. Couchbase view has only one index, so you can have only one "between" per view.

But you can create 2 views that will `emit` "xp equal to 20 AND level between 9 AND 50" and "xp equal to 20 AND cars BETWEEN 100 AND 200" and then intersect result arrays on app-side.
For more info about composite keys view this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076267/composite-views-in-couchbase).

Comment: Is the only solution to use elasticsearch if you want to use couchbase and your backing store but need to retrieve docs based on more than one index?

Comment: Yes, elasticsearch would be the best option for this.